# How does Verilog interpret multiplication by a single bit?

Tags: verilog

I have a conditional 2-bit variable coming in.  Based off its value, the current value is either incremented or decremented. By that, I mean:

```
module verilog_block(clk, cond, incr, curr_val)
input clk;
input [1:0] cond;
input [5:0] incr;
output reg [5:0] curr_val;

always @ posedge(clk)
begin
curr_val <= curr_val + (!cond[1] - cond[1]) * incr * cond[0];
end

endmodule
```

Sorry if I made any mistakes, I haven't checked this specific code, as I am just trying to illustrate my question.  If `cond[0]==0`, I don't want `curr_val` to change (irrespective of `cond[1]`).  If `cond[1]==1`, I want `curr_val` to reduce by `incr`, and if `cond[1]==0`, I want `curr_val` to increment by `incr`.

I think this works, theoretically, but my goal is to expand this into a much larger code.  Therefore, it needs to be optimized.  I know that the `*` operator can be slow and require a lot of resources, but I am not sure if that applies to the case of multiplication with only one bit.

If you can spot a way to make this code optimized for area, please let me know.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Any good synthesis tool will optimize multiplication where it can, especially when it involves multiplication by zero or any power of 2. But you've created a very hard to read operation. Why not write it the way you said it:

```
always @ posedge(clk)
  begin
     if (cond[0]==1) 
       curr_val <= curr_val + (cond[1]==1) ? -incr : incr;
end
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the response.  I suppose what i am trying to do is minimize the amount of logic gates.  I suppose that the synthesis tool will take care of it to an extent.  I really don't know how "smart" synthesis tools are!

Comment: They're very very smart!  And Verilog isn't about telling the tools which gates to create, it's about telling the synthesiser what you want to happen - the clearer you do that, the better chance it has of using less logic.